# Best practice to retrieve a token, access backend and Graph API

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, pkce

What are the best practices for SSO (single sign-on) in the frontend with OAuth 2.0 using authorization code flow with PKCE and accessing the Graph API in the backend?

Earlier I was using react-adal and the implicit flow to retrieve a token in the frontend and access the backend with that. The backend uses the azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter Library.
After the request the backend accesses the Graph API to get needed Information. It was a Web Application in Azure AD.

Currently I access the id token and the access token in the frontend with the msal-react. So this means now I'm using the SPA (single-page application in Azure AD) with authorization code flow. In the frontend I retrieve both: the access token and the id token. To access the backend I need the id token. But I need the access token too, so that the backend could access the Graph API. I don't think this is a good idea to send both of them in Header or to send it at all. Both the frontend and the backend use the same Azure Application. The backend has a Secret. Important is that I do not need the frontend directly access the Graph API.
But is this a good approach to send both the id token for the backend authentication and the access token to access Graph API on the backend side?

Comment: Did you consider OBO flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#protocol-diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks great, we always use MSAL to get the tokens then pass them to the backend to auth and call the API you want, feel free to use it.

Comment: Do you send both of them? The id token and the access token? You can access the backend only with the id token. But you cannot access the Graph API without the access token.

Comment: @JetBrains Why not? What is your concern about it?

Comment: @Jot-Wang Is it not a double work and as a natural consequence a security weakness? I mean the backend has a Client Secret. Why not use that to retrieve a token to access the Graph API (= user data)?

Comment: @JetBrains You mean use the client credential flow to get the access token in the backend? If so, the access token is from the app credential, not the user credential, the user‘s login is meaningless. If you mean to use a user-involved flow again, I think it is a double work, because you have already got the access token in the frontend.

Comment: how do you send the access token to the backend? The "Authorization" Header is the id token. What about the access token?

Comment: @JetBrains About how to achieve it specifically, I think you need to ask it in a new question, including the details about the scenario and the things you have tried, it is a different question from the original topic.